# How to avoid the automatic disk check every 30 reboots?

Tags: power-management, shutdown, system-settings

It it has to do a disc check from being powered down 30 times like that.I have to do it that way cause it wont power down regularly and I'm running Linux ultimate edition x64 2.3. I know its out dated but I can upgrade. PLEASE HELP! I've tried everything and I'm completely clueless.

Comment: This is really hard to understand (I sympathize that no everyone has English as a strong language, but this question is on the border of the unintelligible...). Are you referring to http://serverfault.com/questions/215327/how-to-disable-automatic-and-forced-fsck-on-disks-in-a-linux-software-raid

Comment: yea that's what I'm talking about bout where do I go in the settings to do that?

Comment: So please take time to rewrite the question so that can be useful to other people too...

Comment: It looks like this question is not about Ubuntu.  `I'm running Linux ultimate edition x64 2.3` that ain't no Ubuntu I've ever heard of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard Linux filesystem is checked for consistency, on mount,  every 30 mount and every month, whatever come first. It is possible to shut off this behavior (*not recommended*) by issuing (1):

```
sudo tune2fs -c 0 -i 0 your_device_here
```

However, filesystems are checked on mount every time the disk not correctly unmounted (say, a forced poweroff, or unplugging an external device); this behavior is **not avoidable**.

Your case seems (after deciphring yur question) more the second one, so in this case your only possibility is to solve the clean shutdown problem.

---

**Note (1), TL;DR version:** more in detail, you have to find the device on which your filesystem resides; you can see this by starting a Terminal Emulator (typically from the dash Alt-Ctrl-T, but it depends on your flavor of Linux) issuing

```
mount
```

in the terminal. For example, on my PC you have:

```
[romano:~] % mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda5 on /home type ext4 (rw)
...
```

so for example the device where my root filesystem lives is `/dev/sda1`, and my `/home` is on  `/dev/sda5`. If you got confused about the Unix way of devices, filesystem and mount point please read [this nice tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-system.htm).

So if you want to remove the safety belts for `/`, in my system I should do:

```
 sudo tune2fs -c 0 -i 0 /dev/sda1
```

...but be warned that now you are running with no safety belts; do not protest when your drive will crash and you lose data. Backup frequently.

Comment: so i did the  sudo tune2fs -c 0 -i 0 /dev/sda1
and it said like mount to -1 and like intervals 0 or something like that

Comment: so does that mean it wont do it anymore?

Comment: Have you read my answer? If the disk is incorrectly unmounted, no setting can avoid the check. Otherwise, the command will avoid the check every 30 reboots. BTW, telling "said sort of..." doesn't help, you should report the full, literal message.